# replace href link text

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

Is my code correct?

```
 function replace_stuff() {
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/oldtexts/g,'');
 }
```

I am trying to remove the string "oldtexts" between an `a href` tag like 
this `<a href ="#">oldtexts</a>` but i still see oldtexts and nothing gets replaced

Comment: `oldtext` will never match `/oldtexts/g`, or is it just a typo? :)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try this one, but this may work. (uses jQuery)

```
$('a[href]').each(function(i){
 if($(this).html()=="oldtext") $(this).html("&nbsp;");
});
```

or

```
$('a[href]').each(function(i){
 $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/regex/g,"blahblah"));//warning : if replaced text contains nothing(""), then this will not work.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged jQuery, so I would suggest to use it:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.html().replace(/oldtext/g, ''));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $('#idofatag').text('replacevalueofoldtexts');
});
```

if you want to trigger this change on a click of a button,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#someButtonid').click(function(){
             $('#idofatag').text('replacevalueofoldtexts');
        });
});
```

http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try using `/\b(oldtexts)\b/g` or the jQuery `.replace`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using jQuery, the cleanest solution seems to be using a [function for `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
$('a').html(function (index, oldhtml) {
    return oldhtml.replace(/oldtexts/g, '');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KTjXg/)

If you want to write a reusable function, you can do that of course:

```
function replace_stuff(index, oldhtml) {
   return oldhtml.replace(/oldtexts/g, '');
}
```

And then you can invoke it on any jQuery object: `$('a').html(replace_stuff);`.